# Node 18: node-rest-client gives weird TypeError in the background post execution is completed

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-rest-client

I am using node-rest-client to make a request.

I am mocking the response with a stream but facing an issue where I am getting this error:

`TypeError: The "stream" argument must be an instance of ReadableStream, WritableStream, or Stream. Received an instance of Socket`

Below is the simple snipet that can be run to see the error.

```
const NodeRestClient = require('node-rest-client').Client;
const nock = require('nock');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
 
// Create a Readable stream from a string
const streamResponse = new Readable();
streamResponse._read = () => {};
streamResponse.push('Hello, this is a streamable buffer response');
streamResponse.push(null);
 
// Define the API endpoint you want to mock
const apiUrl = 'https://api.example.com';
 
// Use nock to intercept the HTTP request and mock the response with a stream
nock(apiUrl)
  .get('/endpoint')
  .reply(200, streamResponse, { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' });
 
// Make a request using node-rest-client
const client = new NodeRestClient();
client.get(`${apiUrl}/endpoint`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }, (data, response) => {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    // Response data will be a Buffer
    console.log('Mocked Streamable Buffer Response:', data.toString('utf-8'));
  } else {
    console.error('Error:', response.statusCode, data);
  }
});
```

below is the stack trace:

```
Mocked Streamable Buffer Response: Hello, this is a streamable buffer response
node:events:495
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

<ref *2> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "stream" argument must be an instance of ReadableStream, WritableStream, or Stream. Received an instance of Socket
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at eos (node:internal/streams/end-of-stream:74:11)
    at IncomingMessage._destroy (node:_http_incoming:234:21)
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:109:10)
    at IncomingMessage.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:71:5)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1384:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I want to understand what is causing this issue. Is there a solution/workaround for this issue?

Comment: Looks like node-rest-client has not been updated since - 14 Feb 2022.

Also, when trying to try to try-catch the TypeError that is captured, that does not seem to work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your version of `nock`?
There is an issue with older versions where `nock` overrides `https.request` on its own, preventing it from passing the logic to check for streams on `node`.
If it's not the latest version, please update to the latest version and try again.   https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/2466

Comment: Changing the nock version to the latest solved this issue